# Webform display for specific roles

Tags: 7, webforms, users

Suppose we have 20 webforms A user which has Admin role as well User1 role should  only view its corresponding webform (eg: weform1 and webform2)rest webform should not display at(`admin/content`,`/admin/content/webform`) when he logged in as a user which is having **User1+Admin** role.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you need to do little customization to achieve this.

1. Check the roles
2. Perform your require action(permission)

[code to check logged in user has both roles?](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2013-11-15/code-to-check-logged-in-user-has-both-roles)

```
global $user;
$roleA = 'administrator';
$roleB = 'user1';
$roleC = 'some other role';
$user_roles = array_values($user->roles);

    if (in_array($roleA, $user_roles) && in_array($roleC, $user_roles)) {
      // Do something.
    }
    elseif (in_array($roleA, $user_roles) && in_array($roleB, $user_roles)) {
      // Do something.
    }
    elseif (in_array($roleB, $user_roles) && in_array($roleC, $user_roles)) {
      // Do something.
    }
```

**Second option.**

You can look [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.